# List all Profiles in a group when using "Profile Search Form" as a Joomla menu item

Tags: profile, search, templates

I have a Job Postings profile that gets recorded on a contribution form. The user is then added to a "Job Postings" group. I'd like to have a Profile Search Form on a Joomla page (menu item) that automatically loads every profile record in that group into a list.

Currently, I have it set up to where the user would have to hit search without any filters to populate the list. Like in these images below:

*What you see on page load:*

[image]

*What you see after the user hits "Search" with no filters. (all records are returned):*

[image]

I'd like the query in that second image ("Displaying Results where: Groups(s) in Job Posting...AND...Group Status 'Added') to be the default search on page load, so that the user gets the whole list of job postings automatically, and then can filter with the search criteria if he or she likes.

Right now I am looking into the Listing.tpl file located at: `/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/templates/CRM/Profile/Page`  and have noticed a variable named `$qill` that seems to hold the search criteria, and some other variables like `$row` and `$search` that also control how information is shown on these types of pages. Maybe there is something that can be done with these variables somehow (if I can find where they get defined)? Is there a simple answer to this I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like force=1 url searching works for profiles too, so just provide a menu link to the page with force=1 on the end of the url, e.g. `https://your.site/civicrm/profile?gid=1&reset=1&force=1`

See https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/the-user-interface/searching-url-support/

Comment: Worked like a charm.